# Nginx as a generic proxy server

Tags: nginx, proxy

I'm trying to use nginx as a proxy-server to get to some APIs that don't support CORS. Part of my config:

```
server {

    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;

    merge_slashes off;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location ~ ^/proxy/(.*) {
        proxy_pass $1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't seem to pass on the GET parameters as I'm getting the same error as when supplying none or an invalid apikey:

```
$ curl -i 'http://localhost:8000/proxy/http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/lists.json?apikey=myapikey'
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Date: Thu, 15 May 2014 15:33:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/javascript
Content-Length: 28
Connection: keep-alive
X-Mashery-Error-Code: ERR_403_DEVELOPER_INACTIVE
X-Mashery-Responder: prod-j-worker-us-east-1c-31.mashery.com

{"error":"Account Inactive"}
```

And I'm not quite getting the [proxy_pass documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I have to pass the GET arguments along manually with `$args`:

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  localhost;

    merge_slashes off;
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    location ~ ^/proxy/(.*) {
        proxy_pass $1?$args;
    }
}
```